# How to get letters from an image using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ocr

i want capture the letters(characters & Numbers) from an image using python please help me how can i do it explain me with any sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you out if your image is clear (positively less Noise).
    Use "PyTesser" Project of Google in this Case. 
 
    PyTesser is an Optical Character Recognition module for Python.
     It takes as input an image or image file and outputs a string.
    
You can get  PyTesser from [this](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/downloads/detail?name=pytesser_v0.0.1.zip) link.
     Here's an example:

```
>>> from pytesser import *
>>> image = Image.open('fnord.tif')  # Open image object using PIL
>>> print image_to_string(image)     # Run tesseract.exe on image
fnord
>>> print image_file_to_string('fnord.tif')
fnord
```

Comment: Hi ,. this one works fine, is it possible to read joint letters in pytesseract

Answer (score 0):

I use tesseract for this.
There is also a Python library for it: https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/

Example from the main page:

```
import tesseract
api = tesseract.TessBaseAPI()
api.Init(".","eng",tesseract.OEM_DEFAULT)
api.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
api.SetPageSegMode(tesseract.PSM_AUTO)

mImgFile = "eurotext.jpg"
mBuffer=open(mImgFile,"rb").read()
result = tesseract.ProcessPagesBuffer(mBuffer,len(mBuffer),api)
print "result(ProcessPagesBuffer)=",result
```

Here is my code for Python3 not using the tesseract library but the .exe file:

```
import os
import tempfile

def tesser_exe():
    path = os.path.join(os.environ['Programfiles'], 'Tesseract-OCR', 'tesseract.exe')
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        raise NotImplementedError('You must first install tesseract from https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=')
    return path

def text_from_image_file(image_name):
    assert image_name.lower().endswith('.bmp')
    output_name = tempfile.mktemp()
    exe_file = tesser_exe() # path to the tesseract.exe file from 
    return_code = subprocess.call([exe_file, image_name, output_name, '-psm', '7'])
    if return_code != 0:
        raise NotImplementedError('error handling not implemented')
    return open(output_name + '.txt', encoding = 'utf8').read()
```